# Plant/Human DNA Fusion?

Tags: science-fiction

I've been working on a series where people merge their DNA with a plants. I mean this in the sense of add adding plant DNA to a humans. My question is, would this kill the human, would it enhance the person or would it have no affect?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm combining plant and beef DNA every time I'm having chilli-con-carne. About the side-effects of the mixture... apologies, but a civilized person doesn't speak of such matters (with maybe the notable exception of their GP or the gastroenterologist s/he was referred to). **That is to say**... _what exactly are you asking?_ Putting some human genes into plants? Or viceversa? Or trying to come with a chimeric type of organism, half-plant half-human or what? The question you are raising is quite ambiguous and potentially too unfocused.

Comment: The edit hasn't helped, it's a question fishing for ideas not a specific problem we can help you solve. What end result are you trying to achieve - what characteristics do you want in the end product of the splicing? Maybe we can help you establish a pathway to get there.

Comment: I voted to leave it closed because "What would it change with the way the human functions or processes things?" is an extremely broad question.  Everything, nothing, and anything in between are all plausible answers.  A similar, on topic question might be something like "If I insert the genes from Plant A into Person B's genome, could it cause [some specific effect]?"

Comment: It happened, folks. A case of [cows with bacteria genome added](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-03-14/genetically-modified-cows-no-horns-in-australia/12018078)

Answer (score 5):

Plants and animals share many genes. In fact, [there is about a 1% match between human DNA and banana DNA](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/interviews/mythconception-we-share-half-our-dna-bananas). That may seem little, but consider that we have thousands of genes - that means maybe a few dozens of human genes can also be found in bananas.

This happens because every eukaryotic organism (i.e.: beings whose cells have a nucleus) on Earth has a common ancestor.

Now, were this a question using the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) tag, then yes the result could be death. Gene editing at random is like playing russian roullete - it may be that nothing happens, it may be that [congratulations you gave yourself cancer](https://www.nature.com/articles/3301946).

With the [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) tag, though? Go wild. I think maybe a third of Marvel's superpowered characters are a result of bizarre genetics. Spiderman comes to mind, his origin story involves transgenics ever since the trilogy with Toby Maguire. Your human/plant chimera might have powers like those of DC's [Poison Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_Ivy_(character)).

Comment: Personal point of view, but `Marvel's superpowered characters` fit with `science-fiction` as much as ... I don't know, find two incompatible things that can be put in to a witty contrast.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi About as well as Lego fits with Meccano?

Comment: @Chronocidal +2 for geekness choice of the contrast -0.5 for witticism

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that every living organism on Earth has a common ancestor. But if you said that about _eukaryotic_ organisms, you could be completely sure. Since eukaryotes include both plants and animals, that qualification would be OK for this question.

Comment: @Spencer I like the way you think, and I'm editing the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

We *could* combine animal DNA and plant DNA using DNA editing techniques, such as CRISPR or something of that nature. That would have the same rough effect of taking a book of classical literature, say Shakespeare's *Hamlet* and then swapping half the passages to random passages from Homer's *Illiad*, except you haven't bothered to translate it, and then handing it to someone and telling them to read it. Except since DNA is more comparable to computer code then a novel, instead of having a confused human who can, at best, understand half of it, we wind up with a computer that is throwing out nothing but error codes.

The 'side effect' here is that there's no way a haphazard combination of DNA systems, or in fact just about *any* combination of DNA systems that diverse could be able to meaningfully combine and produce any kind of working side effect. You wouldn't even wind up with some kind of a monstrosity / eldritch abomination, you'd just end up with DNA that doesn't work at all. Of course, if you only altered part of the DNA with tree DNA, or part of the tree DNA with human DNA, then that part wouldn't work and everything else would and then you'd get that monstrosity / eldritch abomination.

Comment: "Ford, there's an infinite number of monkeys out there who want to discuss the script for Hamlet they've worked out!"